# Android libGdx how to make a piano tile?

Tags: android, libgdx, game-engine

I want to make an game like Piano Tiles for that I need to know what for objects the piano tiles should be? A texture, a button, an Imagebutton?

I should change the color when you click on this. What is the best(fastest) way to do this?

Comment: It can be any of those, I recommend using a Sprite. you can change the color changing the image of the Sprite.

Comment: what is the difference between an texture and a sprite

Comment: I recommend a table with button actors. These already have all the functionality you need like registering input, upstate, downstate, etc. All you need to do is place them in a raster and add a `ClickListener` to them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a white Texture and then put a color filter in libGDX to change color. Or you can use ShapeRenderer which is pretty easy to use, specially for rectangles. All you would have to do is set the size and position, and then the color. The fastest way would be ShapeRenderer since it would not have to load the texture into RAM.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Actors. You can draw a Texture or, as Jorge said, you can use ShapeRenderer in the draw method. Then you can add a ClickListener and you can call setColor(). So in the draw method you have to call getColor() and set the batch color (or the ShapeRenderer color).

WARNING: if you use ShapeRenderer, call batch.end() before and batch.begin() at the end.